# Why Tab Layout's layout is neither scrollable or fit screen inside a fragment?

Tags: android-layout

So i have a bottom navigation bar and in one of them it holds a tablayout consists of 3 tabs. Like the below image:
  [The Tablayout is inside a fragment, where it's not scrollable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Ut9.png)

The second issue other than not scrollable is, it doesn't fit the screen. Here is the android studio UI with blueprint image. (**Please do compare with previous image and you will see the right most helloworld is not fitting in the screen and also couple of hello world is not scrollable**!)

[Tab Layout's Fragment not fitting the screen!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z6CO.png)

Partial of my home_fragment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tool"
    >

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabPaddingBottom="-1dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
            app:tabPaddingTop="-1dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tablayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my Category.xml (where it doesn't fit the screen)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginStart="280dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
        android:text="YYYYYYYYYYYUU"
        android:textSize="22dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="156dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried almost all StackOverflow question regarding this problem, but nothing did work for me!May be i just screwed up somewhere, as i am a noob programmer! Any help good people?